# How to auto-populate Google form with page breaks?

Tags: google-apps, google-forms, auto-populate

What I am trying to do is very simple, yet there doesn't seem to be a way to do it.
Here is what I am trying to do:

1. Create a google form with 2 page breaks.

   The first page asks 1 question (from a drop down).
2. When you hit continue, I want to have the 2nd page with some fields auto-populated based on the question chosen from the 1st page.

I am aware of the "[Get pre-filled URL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/160000?rd=1)" option Google offers, however it only gives me an URL based on the fields I pre-filled.

The easiest thing would be to tell the 1st page break to "Continue to this URL", however that option does not exist.

How can I integrate this tool with page breaks?

In summary, I want to choose from a dropdown which then takes me to a pre-filled form based on that answer.

Any idea if that's possible?

Comment: the if statement does not work...

Answer (score 1):

With Google Forms alone, I don't believe this is possible.

If your end goal is a pre-filled form based on a single first selection, it might be better/easier to have the original option just as links to those separate pre-filled forms rather than a second page within the one form.